# how to add a qpushbutton using model.insertrow pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Basically I need to add a `QPushButton` to the end of every row of `QTableView`.

Here is how I insert a row:

```
for row in rows:
    timestamp = QStandardItem("%s" % (row[6]))

    tbModel.insertRow(0, (timestamp)))
```

I tried Things such as:

```
tbModel.insertRow(0, (timestamp, QStandardItemModel(QPushButton("Hi"))))
```

or at the end of `for` loop

```
tableWidget.setIndexWidget(tbModel.index(0, last_index), QPushButton("hi"))
```

But they both fail.

I Just want to add a button to the end of every row or add a button on the last column.

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want the last column to have buttons?

Comment: @eyllanesc, yes

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the setIndexWidget method passing the proper QModelIndex:

```py
column = tableview.model().columnCount() - 1
for row in range(tableview.model().rowCount()):
    index = tableview.model().index(row, column)
    button = QPushButton("Hi")
    tableview.setIndexWidget(index, button)
```